# How to use printk to print a physical address (aka phys_addr_t)?

Tags: linux-kernel, printk

I want to print real physical address that is stored in a variable of type `phys_addr_t`. Now I'm doing something like this:

```c
phys_addr_t paddr;
...
paddr = virt_to_phys(some_virt_addr);
pr_info("%pa", &paddr);
...
```

As for [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt):

```auto
Physical addresses types ``phys_addr_t``
========================================

::

    %pa[p]  0x01234567 or 0x0123456789abcdef

For printing a ``phys_addr_t`` type (and its derivatives, such as
``resource_size_t``) which can vary based on build options, regardless of
the width of the CPU data path. Passed by reference.
```

but I'm a bit confused about `Passed by reference`, because it is already something like reference. So my actual questions are:

- How to correctly print `phys_addr_t` using `printk`?
- What does `Passed by reference` mean here?
- What does the `[p]` postfix of `%pa[p]` mean?

If my example is not correct or inefficient, please show me how it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it correctly:

```c
phys_addr_t paddr = 0x1234;
printk(KERN_INFO "%pa\n", &paddr);
// Result: 0x0000000000001234
```

"Pass by reference" means to pass *a pointer to the physical address* you want to print (`&paddr`) instead of directly passing its value (`paddr`).

The `[p]` suffix in the documentation means that the last `p` is optional. You can use `%pa` or `%pap`. The final `p` is not necessary and also doesn't change the output format (as you can see [from the source here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/lib/vsprintf.c#L1808)).